# google.script.run.function() call from HTML not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm calling a function from a dialog HTML file bound to my google sheet. I copied the code from [google development](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms_user_interface) & wanted to call a simple function. However, it does nothing.  I tried various things, but I just cannot get it to work. Bouth the script & HTML are bound to my spreadsheet.

Here is my script:

```
// Use this code for Google Docs, Slides, Forms, or Sheets.
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Dialog')
      .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

and here is the simple HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: It  should work. But the logs probably moved to view>stackdriver logging

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
GS:

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah3');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}

function doSomething() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("I was called.")
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      window.onload=function(){
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();})
        .doSomething();
      }
      console.log("I am here");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: NOTE: for this to work you must also include your function ```onOpen``` in the ```.gs``` file.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I don’t believe that is correct. I tested this. The onOpen just creates a menu.

Comment: @Cooper, thanks a lot! I tried your code and it works perfectly. You made my day.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf, Indeed. I just added the OnOpen() function to create a menu. This menu allows me to call the openDialog(). For the rest, all the code shared by Cooper works perfectly.

Comment: In the google script editor, when I select >>Run>>"Enable new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8" then the above script stops from working. So it seems that Chrome V8 is not supporting this anymore. Needs to be reported

Comment: I guess I had left the body off on my last edit.  I fixed it.

Comment: But I just tested it in V8 and it runs for me.