# Google.script.run isn't doing anything

Tags: google-apps-script

I am just beginning with App Script and am unable to run a function using google.script.run. Ive included code below its pretty much copied and pasted from the App script sight so not sure whats wrong. Also my console and log aren't returning anything. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
Code.gs 
    function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  Logger.log(e);
  
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
  console.log('I was called!');
}
```

Index.HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62291869/7215091

Answer (score 0):

**Two things:**

1. `Logger.log(e);` will never log anything if it is positioned after a `return` statement. `return` makes a function return a value / content and finish after this - without running any code located after the return statement.
2. If `function doSomething()` does not run and return anything - most likely it is because you tried to run `doGet(e)` manually from the script editor. This is not how it is intended.

   - You should deploy your code as a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and execute it by opening the WebApp URL in a browser window.
   - To see if your functions ran correctly and logged something, go on `View -> Executions`
   - Be careful with case sensitivity (`index` vs `Index`).

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I should have clarified that I am running it as a deployed web app. When I run the function doSomething from the IDE it works as expected. Ive also checked the Executions and it says everything has been completed.

Comment: So you could verify that `doSomething()` completed successfully, but you still cannot see the logs from the executions dashboard?  Should look like this if you expand it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YByKiYB7QkUofnp42TKR74Z0x3p3RRFB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's right. My Executions look like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vpDTVc2v8cCQUF-Cvxif4k83K7RtkMqO/view?usp=sharing and my logs look like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZogLVhaGI7YJkQ2vvboT3amhDyVGSEea/view?usp=sharing

Comment: To see the logs after running a WebApp you should view them from `View -> Executions` instead of `View-> Logs` - see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rk_lps0aUu00n3JiuhJ4O8BcNImQfROw/view?usp=sharing